# Why can't I key in a string in Golang map?

Tags: go

I'm writing a function in go to remove duplicate characters in a string.  Here is my approach.  When I run the following test, why do I get this error?  I'm new to Go and used to more dynamic languages like Ruby/Python.

```
panic: assignment to entry in nil map [recovered]
    panic: assignment to entry in nil map
```

**source.go**

```
func removeDuplicate(s string) string {
  var m map[string]int
    var c_string []string = strings.Split(s, "")
    for i :=0; i < len(c_string); i++ {
      m[c_string[i]] = 0
    }
    for i :=0; i < len(c_string); i++ {
      m[c_string[i]] = m[c_string[i]] + 1
    }
  var (
        result string = ""
    )
    for i :=0; i < len(c_string); i++ {
      if m[c_string[i]] < 1 {
      result  = result + c_string[i]
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

*source_test.go*

```
func TestRemoveDuplicateChars(t *testing.T) {
  got := removeDuplicateChars("abbcde")
    if got != "abcde" {
        t.Fatalf("removeDuplicateChars fails")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you haven't actually initilize/allocated `m`, you've only declared it. Make this; `var m map[string]int` into `m := map[string]int{}`.

Which does initilization and assignment both in the same statement. You could also add another line `m = make(map[string]int)` which would prevent the error though I personally prefer the compacted syntax.

fyi your code is barfing on this line; `m[c_string[i]] = 0`, the error message should make sense when combining that with the information above.